# Deploy non-web Node app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node app used **only in a scheduler**. But heroku keeps trying to call npm start on in.

```
State changed from starting to crashed
Process exited with status 1
State changed from crashed to starting
Starting process with command `npm start`
```

Even with a dummy worker in Procfile:

```
worker: echo 1
```

There's always a web process added at deploy:

```
Default types for Node.js -> web
```

Any ideas on how I could get rid of heroku continuously trying to npm start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a direct solution, but you could easily scale down your web processes to 0.

`heroku ps:scale web=0`